# 404 in files urls in Laravel 5

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel

I have a little problem with Laravel.

My application has a part where the user can upload a template. The app creates a folder with this templates and the user can open a preview of this template.

The problem is:

- The url localhost/manager/templates/1/ open the correct index.html but is not able to find the css, js, img,...

This is my htaccess (in /public):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

The folder are this way in the server:

-public

--asset

--manager

---templates

----1

-----index.html

------css

-------style.css

The apache returns 404 and after doing several changes in htaccess sometimes I received 404 from Laravel.

Sorry for my poor english.

Thanks

Comment: how are you referencing the css ?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem of the url references for your assets. Check laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#urls

> **asset()**
>
> *Generate a URL for an asset using the current scheme of the request (HTTP or HTTPS):*
>
> $url = asset('img/photo.jpg');

This helper function will generate the full url that you need.

For example, for a link to css:

```
<?php
$url_css = 'css/'; // Into public directory.
?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $url_css . 'mycss.css';?>">
```

For a script:

```
<?php
$url_scripts = 'js/'; // Into public directory.
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $url_scripts . 'myjs.js';?>"></script>
```

For an image:

```
<?php
$url_images = 'img/'; // Into public directory.
?>

<img src="<?php echo $url_images . 'myimage.png';?>" />
```

You need to pass the $url variable to your html (or script) files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Allan but in this case this solution not work for me.

The files that the user can upload into my server are pure html and I can't force the user to include blade components.

Comment: The code I write is an example. On top ("asset()") has another example without blade ($url = asset('img/photo.jpg);). You need pass the variable to your html, and replace my {{ asset('...') }}